# Lua find "\x" in the player names

Tags: lua

the players on my server are joining with Emojis on his names and that is not permitted, I tried to create a if check, but it doesn't work properly

```
if string.find(playerName, "%^") or string.find(playerName, '%\') then
    deferrals.done("Por favor, elimine sus emojis y códigos de color de su nombre.")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax highlighting already tells you what's wrong: `\` is used in Lua as an escape character, so the `'` behind it doesn't close the string which instead goes on until the next `'` smoewhere in your code. Use `\\` if you want a single `\`

```lua
if playerName:find("%^") or playerName:find("%\\") then
   deferrals.done("Por favor, elimine sus emojis y códigos de color de su nombre.")
end
```

---

By the way; if you don't need patterns in your search, you can disable them by passing `false` as the second argument to `string.find`:

```lua
if playerName:find([[^]], 1, false) or playerName:find([[\]], 1, false) then
   deferrals.done("Por favor, elimine sus emojis y códigos de color de su nombre.")
end
```

---

And just in case, try adding an `or true` to the condition, so it activates for all player names; that way you can find out if it's the condition itself that fails, or the code inside the if block.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I already test that out, I need to check if the playername contains "\x", because that's how the emojis starts, with \x

Comment: @EnzoGiova Try writing the player names to a file or to the console to make sure that Lua actually gets it that way; it's possible that Lua already gets the string with a unicode character for the emoji.